# Recognizing Matching Colors in a Game Grid from a Camera Image

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, color

I am relatively new to Mathematica, having taken my first serious dive into it this week.  As a fun project to teach myself some of the basics, I've come up with a goal of optimally solving a game called "Chromazone".

The idea is that you start with a 13x13 board made of 6 colors, and the middle spot is "captured."  You select colors and any consecutive blocks of that color touching the middle (black) captured area becomes captured as well.  The game is complete when you've captured the entire board, and the goal is to complete in as few moves as possible.

To make it additionally challenging, I took a picture of the game board with my cellphone, and am using that as a starting point.  Here is the picture:

[image: ChromaZone Sample Image]

After researching different approaches for a couple of hours, I've settled on the following algorithm to interpret the board into a Table I can manipulate for solving later:

1. Resize the image to dimensions that are exact multiples of 13x13 (I chose 520x520, making each square 40x40)
2. Split the image into 40x40-sized square units.
3. Interpolate the color of that square by taking the average.
4. Match the color to one of the standard 6.

I'm somewhat stuck on #4.  I've experimented with multiple approaches but there is enough error in the color matching that I can't quite get it correct.  My first approach was to use the `Nearest` function to match the result of `DominantColor` against the standard 6.  Then I converted the result into indices:

```
Grid[Table[
  Table[Nearest[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ {Yellow, Orange, Green, 
       Red, Blue, Purple} -> Automatic, 
    List @@ DominantColors[
       ImageTake[
        Import["I:\projects\Chromazone\WP_20141015_004.jpg"], {y, 
         y + 40}, {x, x + 40}], 1][[1]]], {x, 0, 480, 40}], {y, 0, 
   480, 40}]]
```

The result is very close to correct, but as you can see below the first incorrect match is the upper-right square, which is detected as orange even though it's yellow:

```
{1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {1} {5} {5} {6} {2} {4} {2} {2}
{5} {3} {6} {6} {4} {2} {3} {6} {2} {3} {5} {2} {2}
{3} {3} {6} {6} {4} {1} {2} {3} {2} {3} {3} {6} {5}
{6} {6} {4} {6} {2} {5} {2} {2} {1} {4} {5} {5} {3}
{1} {4} {6} {5} {2} {1} {3} {2} {1} {3} {5} {1} {2}
{6} {4} {5} {3} {6} {5} {6} {1} {6} {1} {2} {2} {5}
{5} {5} {6} {6} {5} {4} {6} {5} {1} {1} {4} {2} {3}
{5} {1} {2} {5} {5} {2} {4} {4} {2} {5} {1} {3} {2}
{3} {3} {6} {3} {5} {2} {1} {6} {4} {5} {6} {3} {6}
{5} {5} {5} {5} {1} {1} {2} {4} {1} {1} {2} {3} {5}
{6} {2} {1} {2} {1} {3} {3} {6} {3} {3} {5} {3} {3}
{6} {1} {6} {2} {3} {6} {2} {2} {4} {2} {2} {6} {6}
{5} {5} {5} {1} {1} {4} {2} {1} {1} {2} {3} {3} {4}
```

Then I stumbled on the `FindClusters` function and thought it might make more sense to separate the squares into 6 clusters, and if there's enough difference between the color sets it should neatly separate into the 6 color categories:

```
FindClusters[
 Flatten[Table[
   Table[ColorQuantize[
     ImageTake[
      Import["I:\projects\Chromazone\WP_20141015_004.jpg"], {y, 
       y + 40}, {x, x + 40}], 1], {x, 0, 480, 40}], {y, 0, 480, 40}]],
  6]
```

However, there are a few dark yellows again that are grouped with orange (when I used 7 clusters instead, to try to separate black, the black still stayed with the green, and the yellows split into two groups, but interestingly there were no false matches):

[image: FindClusters result]

I'm running out of ideas to get a more accurate result short of hard-coding the correct color match for the exception squares (which I'd really like to avoid).  One more thought I had was to try some sort of image enhancement to counteract the obvious lighting artifact, where the cellphone camera made the center brighter than the edges.  Maybe if I used some circular filter to brighten the outer edge, the `FindClusters` result would not have false matches any more - but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to get a more accurate detection of each grid square's color within these constraints?

Comment: a better initial image could simplify the task a lot

Comment: Agreed.  Actually the real reason I am using a cellphone camera is because the game is on my tablet, and I needed a way to transfer it to a computer.  I've tried multiple times to improve the image quality but I've got a pretty poor cellphone camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a first pass at this problem.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwHZe.jpg"];

getHue = First[DominantColors[#, 1][[1]] ~ToColor~ Hue] &;

hues = Map[getHue, ImagePartition[img, 40], {2}];

plot = Map[Hue, hues, {2}] // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

I tried to use [`ClusteringComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClusteringComponents.html) to further quantize these hues but I got a bad result.  *Edit*: After a rethink I have it working OK now:

```
labels =
 ClusteringComponents[hues, 6,
   DistanceFunction -> (Min @ Abs[{#, # - 1} - #2] &), 
   Method -> "Agglomerate"];

labels // Grid
```

> $\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
>  5 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 \\
>  3 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 5 \\
>  6 & 6 & 4 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 3 \\
>  1 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 \\
>  6 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 5 \\
>  5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
>  5 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
>  3 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 6 \\
>  5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 \\
>  6 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 3 \\
>  6 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 6 & 6 \\
>  5 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: Can you explain what `~ToColor~ Hue` means or point me to a documentation reference?

Comment: @mellamokb Okay, first `arg1 ~func~ arg2` is just another way to write `func[arg1, arg2]` and I am somewhat notorious around here for using it.  As for `ToColor` I forgot that it is almost undocumented, referenced only in [the error message](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/ToColor/tocol.html).  It converts colors from e.g. `RGBColor` form to `Hue` form.  I used it to extract the hue value for each square.

Comment: I discovered that my first approach using `Nearest` actually gets the board 100% correct if I use a value of `Yellow` that is more similar to the yellows in the image.

Comment: @mellamokb Yes, that makes sense.  I was hoping for something more automatic that did not require you to specify the target colors.

Comment: Thanks btw for taking the time to engage with my contrived question, I am learning a lot and it is fun :)

Comment: @mellamokb You're welcome.  Please see my update; I needed a couple of changes but I finally got my original idea working properly.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around that last part.  I think I understand `ClusteringComponents`, but I'm not sure the logic behind your distance function, and after reading the article on [`Agglomerate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/HierarchicalClustering/ref/Agglomerate.html) I'm afraid I don't understand that either :(

Comment: @mellamokb The distance function is needed to handle the fact that hue is cyclic; a hue of 0.01 is very close to 0.99 and I needed to account for that.  As for `Method -> "Agglomerate"` I'll be honest: I just tried methods until I found one that worked; fortunately it was the first one I tried. :-)

Comment: Interestingly, if I take my original second idea and simply replace `FindClusters` with `ClusteringComponents` (and use 7 clusters instead of 6), I get a 100% correct grid.  However I'm wondering why `FindClusters` would group things differently than `ClusteringComponents` - they both appear to use `EuclideanDistance` with color/image data.